# JQuery validation plugin - change border colour of the asp textbox

Tags: jquery, .net, webforms

I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate my .net web form asp text fields. The validation works well, but I want a bit more by changing the asp textbox border colour once the field is invalid. I see a lot of material is regarding to set the colour of the error message but not the textbox field. Some skills do not work quite well with .Net. Anyone know how to use JQuery validation plugin to achieve this??

My current codes are as below:

ASPX page

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Your Email" class="QueryLabel"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" name="txtEmail" class="QueryBox" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox><br /><br />

            <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name" class="QueryLabel"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" name="txtFirstName" class="QueryBox" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:TextBox> <br /><br />

            <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name" class="QueryLabel"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" name="txtLastName" class="QueryBox" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> <br /><br />
```

jS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form1").validate({ 
                rules: {      
                    <%=txtEmail.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    <%=txtFirstName.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    <%=txtLastName.UniqueID %>: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                }, messages: {},         
                errorClass: "error-class",
                validClass:"valid_class",
                errorElement: "em",
                success: function(label) {
                    label.addClass("valid_class").append('&#10004;')
                },
            });
        });
```

css file

```
  .error-class {
        color:#ff0000;  
    }

    .valid_class {
        color:#032d3a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following css:

```
.error-class.QueryBox {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kblau! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

html file :

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control IfErr" placeholder="Enter your name..."><br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control IfErr" placeholder="Enter your email..."><br>
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control IfErr" placeholder="Enter your password..."><br>
<input type="text" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword IfErr" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your confirm password..."><br>
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control IfErr" placeholder="Enter your mobile number..."><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" >
</form>
```

CSS file :

```
<style>
.error-class {
color:#ff0000;  
}
.valid_class {
color:#032d3a;
}
.error-class.ifErr {
border-color: red;
}
</style>
```

jquery script :

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

        $("#myform").validate({
          onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            },
          rules:
          {
              name:
              {
                required:true,
              },
              email:
              {
                required:true,
                email:true
              },
              password:
              {
                required:true
              },
              confirmPassword:
              {
                required:true,
                equalTo:"#password"
              },
              mobile:
              {
                required:true,

              }

          },
          messages: {},

errorClass: "error-class",
validClass:"valid_class",
errorElement:"em",
success: function(label) {
label.addClass("valid_class").append('&#10004;')
},
})
});
<script>
```